# IEnumerable is not populating with expected data when using a ternary operator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ienumerable, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using the following IEnumerable to create a `EncounterEvents`.

Everything is populating great except the last property which is called `IsManaged`.

It's a boolean, and I want it to be `true` if at least one of the `EncounterTypeId` values in the group is 99.

But even though I have verifed that at least one `EncounterTypeId` is 99, it's always false.

If I manually set it like `IsManaged = true`, then it's fine too.

Here is my code:

```
var encounterList = dungeonResults.GroupBy(x => new { x.GameType, x.GameId })
 .Select(group => new EncounterEvents
 {
     CharacterName = group.Select(g => g.GeneratedName).FirstOrDefault(),
     EncounterId = group.Select(g => g.ChapterId).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
     EncounterName = String.Join("; ", group.Select(g => g.ChapterName).ToArray()),
     IsManaged = group.Select(g => g.EncounterTypeId).FirstOrDefault() == 99 ? true : false
 })
 .ToList();
```

Is there anything I need to do to get it to populate correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: `if at least one` - then apparently you need to use `Any()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: @GSerg I tried using `Any()` but I got errors about converting ints and booleans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `group.Select(g => g.EncounterTypeId).FirstOrDefault()` is only evaluating the first record in the group, and it's probably not 99 in your case.

You could better use `group.Any(g => g.EncounterTypeId==99)`.

to clarify, the final expression would be:
IsManaged = group.Any(g => g.EncounterTypeId==99)

it will assign true if any of the items in the collection being evaluated is true.

Comment: Do you mean like `IsManaged = group.Select(g => g.EncounterTypeId).Anyt( )== 99 ? true : false`

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell No. That is the complete expression you should use.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell, .Any() returns true, if at least one element of the sequence satisfies the provided predicate. Thus .Any(g => g.EncounteredTypeId == 99) checks if *any* of the elements in the sequence has EncounteredTypeId equal to 99